# Can't boot my android after changing permissions

Tags: root-access, boot, permissions

I recently rooted my android (Nexus 4).
I wanted to make /system folder permissions 777, I needed that for another application. I got Root Explorer application, and changed permissions to 777. Then root folder disappeared and hanged up.
I tried to restart my phone, but now it doesn't even boot up. What should I do? ... Please, don't tell me I bricked my phone.. It was just permissions, nothing more... I have no idea how to recover now.

When I do `adb shell`, I also get mesaage:

```
/system/bin/sh: /system/etc/mkshrc[9]: getprop: can't execute: Permission denied
```

Also I can't go to root mode (adb root) in console, from $ to #.. so it means.. I even can't change permissions anymore?

Comment: 777 is a potentially dangerous setting. It's like removing the front door to your house. I don't know the Nexus 4, but you should be able to recover by re-flashing your ROM (be it stock or custom) from your computer, using whatever software is appropriate for the Nexus 4 and your computer's OS. (And please tell me you backed up your data before rooting).

Comment: Yes, I backed up everything. So no worries about that. I just worry, that I could lose this phone by itself.. I will try flashing. Just found package for my nexus.

Comment: Could it be you've told root explorer to apply the permission recursively? If so, the easiest way by far is to flash the ROM again. Everything else will be like re-collecting the feathers of a pillow ripped-open during storm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hoped you made a backup:-)

Try to reflash the ROM on your phone in the recovery mode and restore your backup.

And NEVER use 777 because now anyone can access your /system.

Comment: Yes. I have backup. I am now flashing my phone. Do you know what alternative could be that I can RWX files in /system? This is for Boot Animation app, it downloads custom boot loading screens, but it can't put them in /system/media/ to replace stock loading screen.

Comment: @KristapsJaremčuks Do you have a superuser app installed? If so, the boot animation app should request superuser privileges. If you grant it, the app will be able to place the animation in /system/media. If it doesn't request su privileges, it's poorly written, and you should use another one.

Comment: Yes, I had SuperSU. I was also prompted and set it to Granted. Same with other applications which require rooted phone, but problems just with this one.

Comment: @KristapsJaremčuks There's always the option to manually put the bootanimation.zip file in /system/media. That's what I do, and I've never had any troubles with it. The permissions should be 644 (rw-r--r--), and owner:group should be set to root:root (0:0).

Comment: Yes, thats what I thought, to put it manually. But it didn't allow me, it says Read-Only. So I was looking for solution how to change RWX..

Comment: @KristapsJaremčuks I get the problem. Your /system is mounted ro. This is enforced regardless of permissions, and not even root can write to it. The file manager I use automagically remounts rw as necessary and back to ro when done. I use [Solid Explorer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=pl.solidexplorer), and I think [ES File Explorer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.estrongs.android.pop) can do this as well. Another option is [Root Toolbox](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lukemovement.roottoolbox.pro) to remount rw from there.

Comment: Thank you! I successfully flashed my nexus. Now I am back to business, and also Boot Animations work (now I can manually put files in /system/media/)!

Comment: @KristapsJaremčuks That's good news. Enjoy your new fancy boot animation, but don't reboot every ten minutes just to see it. ;)

Comment: There is no other way to preview animation. :( Preview option kinda doesn't work, drops some ads, and thats it. But I found animation that I will probably stick with.